# Symfony 1.4 send mail with Swift Mailer in a Task headers already sent

Tags: symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

I have a symfony Task that calls a class that ends up sending an email alert with Swift Mailer  when some conditions arrises, the problem I am having is that when I run it, I get an oputput in the CLI about some header already being sent.

```
A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Problem in FooLibrary sendEmailAlerts: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by.
```

This happens in my local dev environment, as well in stage, my local is Mac OS X 10.7 with PHP 5.3.15 my stage is Linux CentOS with PHP 5.3.17.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I am able to send one or two of the mails in the queue, but then I get the error, and no more emails are sent.

Comment: The task returns the first error (about the session) which causes the second, because any output displayed raises the "headers already sent" error (when you try to send headers afterwards). Did you try to track down why you have the `session_start` error?

Comment: What I've been thinking that could be the cause of the session already started error, is that the method we have to send the email with Swift Mailer, makes use of: 

    $context = sfContext::createInstance($configuration);

Comment: Yes. Normally you would use `sfContext::getInstance()` which will make sure it is not instantiated twice, but in tasks it will raise the 'default context does not exist' error. Do you really need the context inside the task? It is usually good practice to avoid that.

Comment: Well, from the task I'm calling a 'system/app wide library' for the project that contains a lot of common logic, one of which is the sendmail one and as for what i've seen most if not all methods are static, guess that's why the context get's instantiated for this:

    $context = sfContext::createInstance($configuration);
    $context->getMailer()->send($message);

instead of just doing something like:

    $this->getMailer()->send($message);